# ImageMagick convert command Unable to Read Font

Tags: fonts, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, node-imagemagick

I'm integrating an ImageMagick command into a Firebase Function written in Node.js. I already have Ghostscript installed and have a full list of fonts available:

```
convert -list font

Path: /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.8-10/etc/ImageMagick-7/type-apple.xml
  Font: AndaleMono
    family: Andale Mono
    style: Undefined
    stretch: Undefined
    weight: 0
    glyphs: /Library/Fonts//Andale Mono.ttf
  Font: AppleChancery
    family: Apple Chancery
    style: Undefined
    stretch: Undefined
    weight: 0
    glyphs: /Library/Fonts//Apple Chancery.ttf
  Font: AppleMyungjo
    family: AppleMyungjo
    style: Undefined
    stretch: Undefined
    weight: 0
    glyphs: /Library/Fonts//AppleMyungjo.ttf
```

Here's my code:

```
exec(`convert ${tempFilePath} -font /Users/emma/Library/Fonts/Nunito-Regular.ttf -fill white -pointsize 60 -gravity center -draw "text 0,300 'this is a label'" ${tempFilePath}`, {stdio: 'ignore'}, (err, stdout) => {
         if (err) {
             console.error('Failed to label image.', err);
             reject(err);
         } else {
             resolve(stdout);
         }
});
```

I also tried:

```
exec(`convert ${tempFilePath} -font Arial -fill white -pointsize 60 -gravity center -draw "text 0,300 'this is a label'" ${tempFilePath}`, {stdio: 'ignore'}, (err, stdout) => {
       if (err) {
          console.error('Failed to label image.', err);
          reject(err);
       } else {
          resolve(stdout);
       }
});
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
convert: unable to read font `/Library/Fonts//Andale' @ warning/annotate.c/RenderType/872
```

Comment: What is in `${tempFilePath}`?

Comment: Try changing `300` to `0` in case your picture is less than 600 pixels tall.

Comment: @MarkSetchell ${tempFilePath} is just the path of the image I'm converting. I downloaded it earlier in the code to a temp directory.

Comment: You said you used `Nunito-Regular` or `Arial` but the error message is about `Andale` - did you really give matching code and error messages? I guess your font file has a space in its name, try enclosing it in double quotes.

Comment: Try using the full path to the font file rather than just the font name. Does that work?

Comment: @MarkSetchell All the error messages were the same regardless of what I wrote there, but let me try the double quotes

Comment: @fmw42 I tried that, but it didn't work either

Comment: On some tools that make use of Imagemagick, they do not use the system ENV variable. So I have seen cases such as with PHP Imagick where it cannot locate the Ghostscript. In those cases the solution was to put the full path to Ghostscript where it uses `gs` in the delegates.xml file of Imagemagick for those lines such as PS, EPS that list `gs`. I know nothing about Firebase or Node, but that is something to look into. See https://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php for delegates.xml and its possible locations. Mine is at /usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/delegates.xml

Comment: @fmw42 - That did it for me. gs could not be found, probably related to a software update. Did a 'brew install gs' on MacOS and it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

As per [@fmw42](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51880472/imagemagick-convert-command-unable-to-read-font#comment90719219_51880472) suggested:

> On some tools that make use of Imagemagick, they do not use the system
> ENV variable.
>
> So I have seen cases such as with PHP Imagick where it cannot locate
> the Ghostscript.
>
> In those cases the solution was to put the full path to Ghostscript
> where it uses `gs` in the `delegates.xml` file of Imagemagick for
> those lines such as PS, EPS that list `gs`.
>
> See https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php for `delegates.xml`
> and its possible locations. Mine is at
> `/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/delegates.xml`

So the possible solution is to install `gs` tool.

On MacOS: `brew install gs`.

Related post: https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=34911.